# Why does my React Portal shows a Blank Page?

Tags: reactjs

*this is my index.html*

```
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div id="portaltest"></div>
```

*this my App.js*

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
import PortalTest from "./PortalTest";

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PortalTest />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

*this is what's in PortalTest.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react";

function PortalTest() {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div>This is the PORTAL DIV</div>,
    document.getElementById("portaltest")
  );
}

export default PortalTest;
```

This suppose to show the contents of *PortalTest.js* instead it only returns a blank page.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` instead of `import { ReactDOM } from 'react'` and it should work.

See this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-stitch-o1m4r8?file=/src/PortalTest.js).

Comment: Why though? Can you elaborate for the less educated like me.

Comment: Oh I see, it worked! I just dont know cause VScode autocompletes that part for me, are they different? thanks by the way

Comment: Just follow the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html on how to create portals but I guess the new React API just conflicts with the deprecated version of `ReactDOM` which is exported by `react`. But there are probably a couple of reasons I don't know anything about @Alex